# How to substract custom date in models.DateField from now()?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, date-format

I still can't find a working solution, hence I decided to throw my first post. Note, I'm a beginner in Django.
Building a portal that displays days since the user has been verified.

I tested my **model** without using custom DateField (*verified_since*), just with **date_joined**, and it works properly - showing the count of days remaining (I countdown from 365 days, I am not worried about the leap year yet) since the user has registered in the database vs. today.

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    verified_since = models.DateField(default=now)

    @property
    def ver_since(self):
        return 365 - (now() - self.user.date_joined).days
```

Now if I use **verified_since** instead *date_joined*, I get an error. I suspect this is due to a different format of a date, or maybe a string format instead of a date which can't be subtracted then from datetime.now()

*verified_since* is manually entered date on the form by user.

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    verified_since = models.DateField(default=now)

    @property
    def ver_since(self):
        return 365 - (now() - self.user.verified_since).days
```

Here is **settings**:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'CET'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = True


TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H:%M',)
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which error is it? Pasting the output from the terminal will be helpful.

Comment: @crimsonpython24 wll, thanks for that, I actually ignored the error ('User has no attribute "verified_since"') thinking there is a potential issue with the date format. Removing "user" from "self.user.verified_since" fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

datetime.now() gives you datetime object, while your 'verified_since' is a date field. So just convert your current datetime to date.

```
>>> verified_since
datetime.date(2022, 4, 8)
>>> datetime.now().date()
datetime.date(2022, 4, 12)
>>> 365 - (datetime.now().date() - verified_since).days
361
```

PS: I don't know what ver_since is for, but logically speaking, it's definitely not "verified since - in days"